# What's the most efficient algorithm for generating all k-subsetsof an n-set?

Tags: algorithm, reference, subset, combinatorics

We are given a set of *n* elements and we'd like to generate all *k*-subsets this set. For example, if *S={1,2,3}* and *k=2*, then the answer would be *{1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3}* (order not important).

There are *{n choose k}* *k*-subsets of an *n*-set (by definition :-), which is *O(n^k)* (although this is not tight). Obviously any algorithm for the problem will have to run in time *Omega({n choose k})*.

What is the currently fastest known algorithm for this problem? Can the lower bound of *{n choose k}* actually be achieved (so that we have an essentially optimal algorithm)?

Comment: [Also posted on CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/54147/755).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, you may flag to request migration.

Answer (score 2):

There is some well-known bit magic you could use for producing all subsets (encoded in the binary representation of a long):

```
long getNextSubset(long subset){
   long smallest = subset& -subset;       
   long ripple = subset + smallest;    
   long ones = subset ^ ripple;       
   ones = (ones >> 2)/smallest; 
   subset= ripple | ones;    
   return subset;
}

void printAllSubsets(int n, int k){
    long MAX=1L<<n;
    long subset=(1L<<k)-1L;
    while((MAX&subset)==0){
         System.out.println(Long.toString(subset, 2));
         subset=getNextSubset(subset);
    }
}
```

`printAllSubsets(4,2)` would yield all subsets in lexicographical order:

```
[00]11
[0]101
[0]110
1001
1010
1100
```

The advantage is, that this code is pretty fast, the downside - it does not work for more than 64 objects.

Comment: Wow, did not thought of it! Nice! The funny thing is that this could actually be useful if you had to do lots of computations for small `k` and small `n`. (I'll go through it in detail---I admit I don't understand how/why it works.) Thanks so much for this. :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be computed using the recusrsive rule:

```
kSubsets(S, k) :
  k=0 or k>len(S):  {}
  else:  { for each i-th item in S: {Si} + kSubsets({Si+1,...,Sn}, k-1 }
```

For example:

```
kSubsets({1,2,3}, 2) =  {
                         {1}+kSubsets({2,3}, 1)}, 
                         {2}+kSubsets({3}, 1)}, 
                         {3}+kSubsets({}, 1)
                        } =
     = {
        {1}+{{2}+{kSubsets({3},0), {3}+kSubsets({}, 0)}}},
        {2}+{{3}+kSubsets({},0)},
        {3}+{}
       } =
     = {
        {1}+{{2}+{{}, {3}}},
        {2}+{{3}},
        {}
       } =
     = {
        {1}+{{2}, {3}},
        {2, 3}
       } =
     = {
        {1, 2}, {1, 3},
        {2, 3}
       } =
     = { {1,2}, {1,3}, {2,3} }
```

Note that T+P means to add the items of T to each item in P (each item in P is a set).

Comment: Nice. I like the approach. However, I was asking for the *most efficient* known algorithm (you'd have to provide analysis and argue that it beats other algorithms). The running time of your procedure seems to be the solution to the recurrence `T(k,n) = O(n-k)*T(k-1, n)` (with the obvious corner cases).

Comment: Also, dynamic programming cound be used to save the list of k-subsets for each subset computed,  but this would use as much space as the size of the answer.

Comment: The running time is the size of the solution, that is the number of items in all the kSubsets, which is O( k*C(n, k) )

Comment: Yes, I came up with an [iterative algorithm](https://github.com/blazs/subsets) with similar running time. I wonder whether the lower bound *C(n,k)* is achievable. If one could do a really clever walk over all binary sequences of length *n* with exactly *k* ones  (visiting almost only such sequences), then that could work. But it's far from obvious... The reason I asked the question is because I want to know what is the current gap between the running time of the best algorithm and the lower bound *C(n,k)*.

Comment: (I upvoted your answer; but I'm not accepting it; let's see whether someone comes up with a good reference/algorithm.)