# Resuming a recursive function from a saved state

Tags: algorithm, recursion, vbscript

I have a recursive function that produces all combinations of length k from a set of n.  Typically referred to as "nCk" ("n choose k").  I wish to set it loose with fairly large values (56C22) which will produce 2,142,582,442,263,900 results.  Due to implementation restrictions (I have to use VBScript, and can't stay logged in to the computer for longer than I am at work), I won't be able to let it run to completion all in one go.  As such, I'd like to periodically save the current state of the function and resume it later...but I can't seem to figure out how to do so.  The recursion is messing with my ability to think this through logically.

I have perused the suggested solutions here on SO, and otherwise searched on "resuming a recursive function", and the like, to no avail.  I would appreciate some pointers (NOT a programming language pun) to get me on the right track.

An actual algorithm (pseudo-code is fine) is preferred to a long-winded explanation that doesn't include actual code.  If you want to actually code it, I'm most familiar with C, C++, Pascal, VB, JavaScript, and VBScript (and, as stated, working with VBScript at the moment).

Here is my recursive function:

```
function nCk(aSet, iSetIndex, aSubset, iSubsetIndex)
    'Found result
    if (iSubsetIndex > ubound(aSubset)) then
        log "output.txt", join(aSubset), 1, false

        exit function
    end if

    'No more characters available
    if (iSetIndex >= ubound(aSet) + 1) then
        exit function
    end if

    'With aSet[iSetIndex]
    aSubset(iSubsetIndex) = aSet(iSetIndex)
    nCk aSet, iSetIndex + 1, aSubset, iSubsetIndex + 1

    'Without
    nCk aSet, iSetIndex + 1, aSubset, iSubsetIndex
end function  'nCk
```

FYI: I'm 50 years old; this isn't homework.

Comment: I would be wary of the amount of output you generate. If you are indeed outputting a line for every possibility it will take several years just for the computer to write all that to a disk at standard hard drive speeds, not to mention that you probably can't afford to save that much data to a disk. If you want a really long running process, maybe you'd be better off getting an AWS box and running it on that.

Comment: The output will be parsed before writing, and invalid results (which will be most of them) will be discarded.

Comment: Have I understood you correctly. You want to write a function which calculate a binomial coefficient for large values, making sure you have resume your work somewhere in the middle?

Comment: @Salvador Dali:  Yes, that is correct.  The program will run for a while (when I am at work), saving its state every so often.  When I log off the computer for the day, the program will be terminated.  When I come in to work the next day, I want to run the program again and have it pick up where it left off and continue from there.  How can I get the recursive function back to the saved state?

Comment: Actually, if there are less than 64 elements you could use this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867033/whats-the-most-efficient-algorithm-for-generating-all-k-subsetsof-an-n-set/35878922#35878922

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing a recursion is not so easy, because to resume the operation you will need to restore the stack, which is not a trivial task. I would go with an iterative algorithm, which is not as elegant as a recursion. But it pays off if interrupting/resuming calculation is needed.

An idea could be:

1. a subset is represented as a vector of 0s and 1s. 0 means the element is not taken, 1 - the element is taken so [1, 0, 1] for the set {1,2,3} means the subset {1,3}. Clearly only vectors of length N are real subsets.
2. see this vector as a kind of stack, it represents the state of your "recursion"
3. the value -1 in this vector is used to trigger the right behavior in the iteration -> similar to returning/backtracking from a recursion.

As algorithm (first, for iterating through all subsets):

```
def calc_subsets(state, N):#N - number of elements in the original set
     while True: #just iterate
        if storeFlag:#you need to set this flag to store and interrupt
            store(state)
            return
        if len(state)==N and state[-1]!=-1: #a full subset is reached
            evaluate(state)
            state.append(-1)#mark for unwind

        if state[-1]==-1:#means unwind state
            state.pop()
            if not state: #state is empty
                return #unwinded last element, we are done
            if state[-1]==1:#there is noting more to be explored
               state[-1]=-1#mark for unwind in the next iteration
            else:# = 0 is explored, so 1 is the next to explore
               state[-1]=1
        else: #means explore
            state.append(0) # 0 is the first to explore
```

`evaluate` is up to you, I just print out the vector:

```
def evaluate(state):
    print state
```

To print all subset of 3 elements one should call:

```
calc_subsets([0], 3)
>>>
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1]
```

and to print only the second part:

```
calc_subsets([0,1,1,-1], 3) 
>>>
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1]
```

Now, the algorithm can be adapted to iterate  only through all subset with a given cardinality. For that, one must keep track of the number of elements in the current subset and trigger unwinding (through pushing -1 into the state vector) if the requested size of the subset is achieved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your specific language implementation, but I believe it's customery to convert recursion to iteration in certain circumstances. When you have an explicit stack, it ought not be too complicated to write it to disc and pick up where you left off.

A generic example:

```
stack = [[argument1,argument2,argument3,...etc.]]

while stack is not empty
  current_parameters = stack.pop

  aSet      = current_parameters[0]
  iSetIndex = current_parameters[1]
  ...etc.

  if ...

else ...
    // push to stack instead of calling nCk
    stack.push([aSet, iSetIndex + 1, aSubset, iSubsetIndex + 1])

if it's time to go home
    write stack to disc
    break
```