# Bitwise operators on BigInteger in C#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, biginteger

## Question

I'm trying to implement [the following Java function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35878922/11808605) in C# using `BigInteger` values so that the 64-bit restriction no longer applies. As a sanity check, I converted the original function using `long` to C# code as well. The problem is, however, that while the version using `long` works, the version using `BigInteger` does not always return the same result.

### Implementations

Implementations of the original function in C#.

#### Get next subset (`long`)

```cs
public static long GetNextSubset(long subset)
{
    long smallest = subset& -subset;
    long ripple = subset + smallest;
    long ones = subset ^ ripple;
    ones = (ones >> 2) / smallest;
    subset = ripple | ones;
    return subset;
}
```

#### Get all subsets (`long`)

Rather than printing all the values like in the original Java code, I intend to use them so I return each value individually.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<long> GetAllSubsets(int n, int k)
{
    long max = 1L << n;
    long subset = (1L << k) - 1L;
    while ((max & subset) == 0)
    {
        yield return subset;
        subset = GetNextSubset(subset);
    }
}
```

#### Get next subset (`BigInteger`)

```cs
public static BigInteger GetNextSubsetsBigInt(BigInteger subset)
{
    var smallest = subset& -subset;
    var ripple = subset + smallest;
    var ones = subset ^ ripple;
    ones = (ones >> 2) / smallest;
    subset = ripple | ones;
    return subset;
}
```

#### Get all subsets (`BigInteger`)

```cs
public static IEnumerable<BigInteger> GetAllSubsetsBigInt(int n, int k)
{
    var max = new BigInteger(1 << n);
    var subset = new BigInteger((1 << k) - 1);
    while ((max & subset) == 0)
    {
        yield return subset;
        subset = GetNextSubsetsBigInt(subset);
    }
}
```

### Expected values

#### The math behind choosing `k` objects from a collection of `n` objects

From [combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination), it's easy to verify if the yielded collection of numbers has the correct number of values using the choose function:

`Choose(n, k) = n! / (k! * (n - k)!)`

#### Example where `long` version works, but the `BigInteger` version does not

The number of ways to draw two cards from a standard deck of 52 playing cards is 1326, but the `BigInteger` implementation yields only 190.

How can I correct the `BigInteger` implementation?

Comment: I'd think you'd want to do `new BigInteger(1) << n` to ensure you don't overflow if `n` is large since `1 << n` is going to be an `int` value before it's passed to the `BigInteger` constructor.  The same goes for `(new BigInteger(1) << k) - 1`

Comment: @juharr it worked, thanks! Could you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing the bit shifts on an `int` before creating the `BigInteger`.  Just change it to create a `BigInteger` value of 1 and then do the bit shifts.  There's even a static property you can use called `BigInteger.One`.

```
public static IEnumerable<BigInteger> GetAllSubsetsBigInt(int n, int k)
{
    var max = BigInteger.One << n;
    var subset = (BigInteger.One << k) - 1;
    while ((max & subset) == 0)
    {
        yield return subset;
        subset = GetNextSubsetsBigInt(subset);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used `+ BigInteger.MinusOne` just to be certain too.